# Scanner usedelimiter get pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I get pattern in usedelimiter? For example:

```
sc = new Scanner(new File("polinom.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter("[+-]");
```

I would like to get sign before sc.next(). Thank you for your helps.

Comment: "How can I get pattern in usedelimiter?" Scanner provides `public Pattern delimiter()` method which returns delimiter used by Scanner. "I would like to get sign before sc.next()" delimiter is token separator and each `nextTYPE()` method returns only tokens, delimiters are ignored so you can't return them.

Comment: There could be another solution but you would need to describe first what your real goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe don't use the **Scanner#next()** method at all. Read in an entire file line using **Scanner#hasNextLine()** in your **while** loop condition and **Scanner#nextLine()** to read the line into a variable then parse the line to acquire the operators used. You can use the **String#split()** method along with a regular expression like `"[\\+\\-\\\\*\\/]"` to split the equation line on either the *plus*, *minus*, *multiply*, or *divide* operators.

Now iterate through the array of split values and build a temp string. Use the length of this temp string along with the String#substring() method against the original line to acquire the operator the split was originally based on. Sounds real confusing right? It's ***kind of*** like reverse engineering the original split process. Here is a code example:

If we have a text file named **polinom.txt** and it contains:

```
2+2-1
3 * 3 + 2 - 1
6+6
44 / 6 + 7-7
6+1+2+4
```

and we run the following code:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("polinom.txt"))) {
    StringBuilder tmp;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine().replace("\\","/");
        System.out.println("EQUATION:\t" + line);

        // Split the Equation line on the +, -, *, and / operators
        String[] equationNumbers = line.split("[\\+\\-\\\\*\\/]");
        String[] operators = new String[equationNumbers.length - 1];
        tmp = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < equationNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\tEquation Number " + (i + 1) + " is: " + equationNumbers[i].trim());
            tmp.append(equationNumbers[i]);
            if (i < operators.length) {
                operators[i] = line.substring(tmp.length(), tmp.length() + 1);
                System.out.println("\t\tOperator after Number is: " + operators[i]);
                tmp.append(operators[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger("Get Operators").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

What you should see within your console window is:

```
EQUATION:   2+2-1
    Equation Number 1 is: 2
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 2 is: 2
        Operator after Number is: -
    Equation Number 3 is: 1

EQUATION:   3 * 3 + 2 - 1
    Equation Number 1 is: 3
        Operator after Number is: *
    Equation Number 2 is: 3
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 3 is: 2
        Operator after Number is: -
    Equation Number 4 is: 1

EQUATION:   6+6
    Equation Number 1 is: 6
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 2 is: 6

EQUATION:   44 / 6 + 7-7
    Equation Number 1 is: 44
        Operator after Number is: /
    Equation Number 2 is: 6
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 3 is: 7
        Operator after Number is: -
    Equation Number 4 is: 7

EQUATION:   6+1+2+4
    Equation Number 1 is: 6
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 2 is: 1
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 3 is: 2
        Operator after Number is: +
    Equation Number 4 is: 4
```

Comment: Using [almson-regex](https://github.com/almson/almson-regex) you can rewrite `"[\\+\\-\\\\*\\/]"` a little more clearly as `charclass ('+', '-', '*', '/')`. In fact, it might have helped you avoid an error because your original expression also matches `\\`.

Comment: Cool...Now you can use '/' and '\' for your divide operator in the text file. Don't use it in code though. Make a conversion if detected.